# Is there a a way to force LookupAccountSid to always return the name in the US locale?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a test that has been failing for seemingly random reasons. Turns out that the non-US Windows installations have localized names for the SIDs, which makes a simple string comparison fail.

Is there a way to always get an english name from [LookupAccountSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsida) regardless of what the OS language is? E.g. I'd always like to get `"LOCAL SERVICE"` and not a localized string.

Comment: Well Known SIDs are the unique ID(s).  The string name is not supposed to be anything else than display text see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids

Comment: *which makes a simple string comparison fail* - this is your error. you not need compare strings at all. you need comare SID in binary form

Comment: The test was for a component that outputs that data as a string, but I guess you're both right and the premise is simply flawed.

Comment: You may use [`GetThreadLocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getthreadlocale) to save the current locale, [`SetThreadLocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale) to the language you want, then call the LookupAccountSid, and finally return to the older locale.